# How to find average of Django ArrayField of integer

Tags: postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I have a following models:-

```
class companyData(models.Model):
    companyId = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
   ratings = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), blank=True,null=True)
```

In database I got arrayField as:-

[3,4.5,2.5]

How to write django ORM query to get average of ratings like this:-

```
a = companyData.objects.filter(companyId='022c4ee5-18a6-4461-8945-dd407be3fab9').annotate(Avg('ratings'))
```

Above query gives error as follows:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 234, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 52, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 848, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
ProgrammingError: function avg(integer[]) does not exist
LINE 1: ...mpanyapp_companyData"."ratings", AVG("compa...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: as error states, `avg(integer[]) does not exist`, you should unnset array first to apply `avg` against it, this might give you an idea:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804281/aggregate-functions-over-arrays

Comment: what you really need is to normalize your database

Answer (score 1):

as answered [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTimGlfovzQue7Gj8EHc3aA8gD3aIpKKoZ9amf16k@mail.gmail.com) , you can create custom function with wanted funtionality:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION avg(double precision[])
RETURNS double precision AS $$
SELECT avg(v) FROM unnest($1) g(v)
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

and usage:

```
t=# select avg('{1,2}'::float[]);
 avg
-----
 1.5
(1 row)
```

Please mind I used `float[]` instead of `integer[]`, based on your data sample `[3,4.5,2.5]`, while your ORM sees `ratings` as `integer[]` for some reason...

Any this is a possible workaround for you, not a solution I guess.

Comment: I appreciate your work dude, but I need Django query?

Comment: After you create above function in your db. Existing jango should start working